# Facebook android SDK4.0 get mail address

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook have change API to 4.0
and how can I get user mail address
because new class is called profile can't get that.
It might callback from graph API?

```
   private void GraphAPIprofile() {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        Log.i("Graph API", response.toString());
                        Log.i("User Mail", object.optString("email"));

                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

I think there have something wrong with me..
please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
if (Session.getActiveSession() == null
        || Session.getActiveSession().isClosed()) {
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("State= " + state);

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                System.out.println("Token=" + session.getAccessToken());
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new GraphUserCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                    System.out.println("User=" + user);

                                }
                                if (response != null) {
                                    System.out.println("Response="
                                            + response);
                                    Toast.makeText(FBConnect.this,
                                            response.toString(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
            if (exception != null) {
                System.out.println("Some thing bad happened!");
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Write this code in `onResume` of your activity or wherever you want to access user's data.

Comment: yes, thanks for reply, I did that yesterday, but I think that was for old API version. They removed session.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x

Comment: No its working fine for me.
the user object contains all the info you need